# Tomcat can't find sever listener class when started from within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, web-applications

I have a webapp which is Maven-enabled. When I run the build with `mvn install` everything looks good, classes are under `WEB-INF/classes`, maven dependencies are under `WEB-INF/lib` and web.xml file is under `WEB-INF/` as they should.

However, when I deploy from within Eclipse using Tomcat 7.x, it can't find the listener class. The com.test.backend.BackendApplication servlet is not invoked either, even though it is configured in the web.xml to load on startup.

I noticed that the classes are not showing up under Eclipse's "Deployed Resources" node on the Project Explorer, but I have no idea how to make it show up there.

Here is the exception I get:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.test.backend.BackendServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.backend.BackendServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4876)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>com.test.backend</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.backend.BackendApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.test.backend.BackendServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.version>3.1.0</maven.version>
        <jersey.version>2.14</jersey.version>
        <jersey.test.version>2.15</jersey.test.version>

        <jackson.version>2.5.2</jackson.version>

        <guice.version>4.0</guice.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ...     
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-war</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <classpathPrefix />
                                </manifest>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Implementation-Build>${build.number}</Implementation-Build>
                                    <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
                                    <Implementation-Vendor>RestApi.com</Implementation-Vendor>
                                    <Built-By>${user.name}</Built-By>
                                    <Built-OS>${os.name}</Built-OS>
                                    <Build-Date>${build.date}</Build-Date>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>

                            <webResources>
                                <resource>
                                    <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                                    <directory>./target/${project.artifactId}</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </webResources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

An help is greatly appreciated! I searched for hours but so far no luck...

Comment: hope you have not manually deployed the app on tomcat. if yes remove the web content from tomcat/webapps and push the content through eclipse.

Comment: Did you check the `Deployment Assembly` of your project?

Comment: @onepotato Yes, the deployment assembly seems correct. Source folder src/main/java into WEB-INF/classes, Maven Dependencies into WEB-INF/lib and src/main/webapp into /

Comment: @junedAhsan no, I didn't do that. Deploying through eclipse. Deploying the war manually actually works fine.

Comment: just for the record now 2 years later almost, what version of Eclipse was that? What version of Dynamic Web Module is set in the Eclipse `Project Facets`? Were you using `m2e` to integrate maven and Eclipse? Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the maven Web project then under deployment assembly add "folder with the listener classes in target folder".

For example if `ServletContextListener` implementation is present in the `package com.company.listeners`, deployment assembly should have the following folder mapping:

**target/<applicationname>/WEB-INF/classes/com/company/listeners**

Should be mapped to

**WEB-INF/classes/com/company/listeners**

I think this is related to class loader hierarchy in tomcat and the class loader used for loading listeners (and classes available for that class loader).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself. After a lot of cursing I realised I didn't have build automatically box checked. (Knew I should never have turned the damn thing off!)

[image]

Solved it for me. Hopefully this post will save someone else's sanity!